# How to organize my database result in an array properly?

Tags: php, database, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I wanted to properly organize my database result in the code so I can handle those result effectively and without much chaos. 
For eg.

```
id          type               prop            value               image_path                                                                 is_primary
28  Leasable space  Total built up area        10001            https://development-stockarea.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/W-00000001-0.jpeg  1
28  Leasable space  Warehouse Identifier    TEST_ARJUN          https://development-stockarea.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/W-00000001-0.jpeg  1
29  Leasable space  Warehouse Identifier    TEST_ARJUN1         https://development-stockarea.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/W-00000001-1.JPG   1
29  Leasable space  Total built up area        1001             https://development-stockarea.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/W-00000001-1.JPG   1
```

This is the data I fetch. Now according to primary keys (id) I want to make proper array structure. It will be mutli-dimensional like

```
arr[28][type]=Leasable Space
arr[28][prop][warehouseidentifier]=test_arjun
arr[28][prop][total built up area]=10001
```

So I am not able to form a way on how can make this structure effectively without any much of chaos. Or are there any good library which can help me do so. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr[$row['id']]['type'] = $row['type'];
    $arr[$row['id']]['prop'][$row['prop']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: Hello Nice thanks for your response. I am fetching the $result array from codeigniter and its showing me error  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array.

Comment: @AbhirajTulsyan if you already have your data in an associative result array you should be able to just use `foreach ($result as $row) {` instead of `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`